# Why is using composer for TYPO3 production deployments discouraged?

Tags: composer-php, typo3

The [official documentation for deploying TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/DeployTYPO3.html) states "The composer install command should not be run on the live environment."

Why is this? As far as I know [deployer](https://deployer.org) - a well received deployment tool for TYPO3 - does exactly this.

Comment: Why not ask whoever wrote that documentation for clarification?

Comment: Mostly because this Q/A would be lost for others then. Very good points in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TYPO3 Recommends Composer as the Main Installation method.

but its good practice to run "composer install" on your local machine (or a CI Pipline like Github Actions) then move the downloaded code to the final destination server. and i think deployer is dooing exaclty that.

this has multiple advantages:

- less dependancies on the production system. (one less software there to be exploited)
- possiblity to run unit tests before deployment
- add additional build steps for your deployment (like compilin sass
  or javascripts)
- ther is no need for credentials of private repositories on the production server

Comment: don't forget: the production server does not need access to any repositories. Especially such as github, bitbucket where every kind of code can be stored or replaced unmentioned.

Comment: No, deployer will run composer install on the actual server.